# NoMethodError in Scores#index

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, nomethoderror

In my game the a user `has_one` score and a score `belongs_to` a user. As the user is playing, I want the score of that user to be visibily incrementing by 1 every second, and then be saved so that the user's score can be visible on a leaderboard. I have already figured out the code to do this with a JavaScript variable, however when I try it with a ruby object I get an error saying:

```
undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass
```

Controller:

```
class ScoresController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_user, only: [:index]

  def index
      @score = current_user.score
      @users = User.all
  end
end
```

View:

```
<div class="score-outline"> Score:<div id="score">0</div></div>
```

Javascript:

```
window.setInterval(
function countscore() {
    if($('#game-area').is(':animated')){    
        <%= @score += 1 %>
        document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = <%= @score %>
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Which file contains your JavaScript? It looks like it's not in the index action's template.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is:**

There is no value set for `@score` variable in your app and you are using + operator.

**solution**

Set `@score = 0` first and then try.

Comment: When I do that I stop getting the error however it does not change the object itself because when I later call on the users score value it still appears empty @pradeep sapkota

Comment: You needs to update your score in database, how you are using sore in table it should be integer not string. Then set default value 0 and every time score increases or decreases update score in database then call sore problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

> undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass

You are trying to add 1 to nil that's why you are getting this error

Use [increment](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/increment) method instead

```
def index
  @user = current_user
end
```

Increment it

```
@user.increment(:score)
```